# How can I assign an array that I received from another file to another array?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, handlebars.js

Whenever I receive an array from another file all I can do is display the whole array. I cannot display a specific element or assign it to another array. I have posted some of the code below.

Below is my .js file used to run node. This is the one that sends the arrays.

```
var titles = [1,2,3,4];
var descriptions = [5,6,7,8];
var dates = [9,10,11,12];
var file_names = [13,14,15,16];

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
res.render('home', { postTitles: titles, postDescriptions: descriptions, postDates: dates, postFileNames: file_names });
});
```

This is my home.handlebars that receives the arrays

```
var myTitles = {{postTitles}};
var myDescriptions = {{postDescriptions}};
var myDates = {{postDates}};
var myFileNames = {{postFileNames}};
```

Comment: The whole array is displayed _because_ you are passing the whole array to the `render` function. If you want to display only one element, then you have to pass that specific element to the `render` function.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen ok but how can you assign the array to another array? I have tried var myTitles = {{postTitles}}; but it does not work

Comment: It seems that you have the wrong idea regarding how templates work. A template is simply the html+css structure _without_ the data. The `render` function's job is to generate a web page.This is done by putting data into the template file (and serving it to the client). No data processing is not done in the template. It is done before the `render` function is called.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I'm sorry I am very new to web programming, How would you recommend I go about displaying what is in the array? Keep in mind that the array's size and content change.

Comment: Just one question: are you trying to take the whole array from server-side and put it within the front-end `<script>` tag?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen initially i was going to display the array in the home.handlebars, but since now I know that is not used for any actual data. I dont know where to display it. The only second place that makes sense is the main file that node runs off. What do you think?

Comment: Check my answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ways to render an array in handlebars template from node backend:

1. When the whole array is intended to be displayed, the [`#each`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration) helper is used.
2. If only one array-element is needed to be displayed, then only that element is passed to the template (with or without the [`#with`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#with) helper).

> Example:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

  var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  res.render('home', {

    theArray: myArray[0]

  });

});
```

3. Most often, AJAX calls are used to dynamically request data from the server into the frontend. This is the preferred way and is the basis of REST API used in all mobile and web apps.
4. It is also possible, to simply to stringify a server-side array and push it into the `<script>` tag:

> Handlebars template:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myArray = {{theArray}};

    // here use myArray to do whatever processing is needed

</script>

...
```

> Server-side code:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {

  var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArray);

  res.render('home', {

    theArray: jsonString

  });

});
```

This is the **least** preferred method as far as I know. But it can the job done.